# Inheriting instance in PHP

Tags: php

I try to call **getTest()** function inside **Child** class. 
First I initialize instance of **Ext** class so I assume main property **$ext** should now contain it. But **Child** class does not inherit it and obtained error message is:

*Call to a member function getTest() on a non-object*

Where is the issue?

```
<?php

 $A = new Main;

 class Main
 {
    protected $ext = null;
    function __construct()
    {
      $this->ext= new Ext();
      new Child;
    }
 }

 class Child extends Main
 {
    function __construct()
    {
      echo $this->ext->getTest();
    }
 }


 class Ext extends Main
 {

    public function getTest()
    {
      return "cool";
    }
 }

 ?>
```

I know that to solve it other way I can use:

```
class Child
{
  private $Main;
  function __construct( &$Main ) { ... }
}
```

but I would like to understand why that does not work..

Answer (score 2):

At the moment on construct the object the atribute don't have a value yet.

You need call to the parent constructor before use the attribute

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    echo $this->ext->getTest();
}
```

Comment: This will give a fatal error, like Maximum function nesting level reached

Comment: When call parent::__construct, it is again calling the child class, and then again child class calling parent..this will go on in a loop.